# products per row in grid view magento go

Tags: magento, categories, magento-go

I am using **magento go.**
I have created a category and assign 8produts to it, **i want to display 4 products in each row** but it show 5-products.

Please give me solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put this code in your category which you want to diplay 4 products, just open your category from admin and open custom design tab and put below code in custom layout update field.

```
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
</reference>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: It Works Perfectly for Categories. Thanks. Though I want to use it within a "new products widget". How would it be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Go to this path: magento_folder/app/design/frontend/mytheme(your_package)/neo(your_theme)/layout/catalog.xml
Write this : `<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>`**

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
" "
" "
" "
</block>
```

**And after that in the same catalog.xml file below add the same code (under :`<catalog_category_layered translate="label">` tag) like this :**

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
" "
" "
" "
</block>
```

**Hope this may help you**